# ANR dialog in my android application

Tags: android

I see a ANR dialog in my android application. 
Can you please tell me if it is possible that my application uses up a lot of memory and GC takes over and uses a lot of time? Or it is something else?

Answer (score 4):

You probably run many things on the UI thread which you should not do. Read this article carefully: [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)